# Formal grammar for the language $L = \{w\in\{a,b\}^*,\,w=xx,\,x=a^nb^na^mb^m,\,n\ge0,\,m\ge0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammar

What is the grammar of this language?

$$L = \{w\in\{a,b\}^*,\,w=xx,\,x=a^nb^na^mb^m,\,n\ge0,\,m\ge0\}$$

For example: $abab$, $abaabbabaabb$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? To start with, do you know a grammar for $\{a^nb^n\colon n\ge0\}$? You might be able to generalize that.

Comment: S -> aSb | epsilon
Is it correct?

Comment: Excellent. Now you need two of those, side by side.

Comment: S -> AB | epsilon
A -> aAb | epsilon
B -> aBb | epsilon

Is it my x? I don't know how to make w=xx.

Comment: Ouch! I didn't notice the $w=xx$ bit. Gotta think on that one. Sorry. Is there a requirement for a context free grammar? I suspect that may not be possible.

Comment: I do not know if there is such a requirement.

Comment: If you have a new question, [ask a new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  ***Do not*** simply edit this question to ask your new question.  (Or worse yet, _do not deface this question_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it in two steps: First a grammar to generate your $x$, or actually strings of the form $Xu^nv^nu^mv^mY$. You can easily adapt the grammar we discussed in the above comments to make these strings. Now you need to create a copying machine to duplicate the string. I used $u$ and $v$ instead of $a$ and $b$ here, intending to convert them to $a$ and $b$ as the copying progresses. Here is a set of productions to achieve this:
$$\begin{aligned}
 X&\rightarrow XR&Ra&\rightarrow aR&Rb&\rightarrow bR&RY&\rightarrow\varepsilon\\
 Ru&\rightarrow Ua&Rv&\rightarrow Vb&XU&\rightarrow XaR&XV&\rightarrow XbR\\
 aU&\rightarrow Ua&bU&\rightarrow Ub&aV&\rightarrow vA&bV&\rightarrow Vb\\ 
\end{aligned}$$
The set is not complete yet! But look: $X$ can spawn an $R$ which moves right past all $a$s and $b$s until it hits a $u$ or $v$, where it converts that to $a$ or $b$ and morphs into $U$ or $V$, which travels left until it hits $X$, where it becomes $a$ or $b$ – that is the copy – and a new $R$ to travel right and continue the process.

You may need a few more productions to finish it off. Perhaps you only need to add $X\rightarrow\varepsilon$ to finish the job.

This is a lot like programming. Think of the nonterminals as little special purpose machines traveling back and forth doing their thing.

Finally, a *disclaimer*: I have not debugged the above! There may well be bugs, like in any program. I will leave the debugging and verification to you. Good luck.

Comment: You could simplify the rules $XU\rightarrow XaR$ and $XV\rightarrow XbR$, dropping the $R$. After all $X$ can always spawn a new $R$.

Comment: this is not context free, right?

Comment: @doniyor: No, it isn't. I asked, and it did not seem to be a requirement. In fact, I don't think a context free grammar for this language can exist. But I am far afield from my expertise here, so take this with more than a grain of salt.

Comment: @Harald:  Indeed this language isn't context-free.  Probably it's easier to prove in this special case, but a generalisation is contained in my [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.1806v1.pdf) on poly-context-free groups (Theorem 3.12: the language $L$ in this question is essentially what I am calling $L^{(2,2)}$ - defined on p.19).